# cmake coverage on unit tests

Tags: cmake, code-coverage

I have a project with source files and unit test files. cmake version 3.16.3.
my CMakeLists.txt has two targets/executables: one for the app and one for ut.

I want coverage turned on ONLY for the ut target.
But it get's turned on for both targets.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(devcpp-lib-template)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2")

# === src related
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(SOURCE_FILES
        lib/library_name.h lib/library_name.cpp
        <snip other files here>
)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# === Unit Tests
project(ut)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
# these turn on coverage
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(UT_FILES
        lib/version.h lib/library_name.h
        <snip ... other files here>
        ut/ut_test1.cpp
)

add_executable(ut ${UT_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
        pthread
        gcov
)
```

When I build the above with target "devcpp-lib-template" (i.e. not "all"), the cmake-build-debug/.../lib/ has *.gcno files (the generated coverage files). This is wrong.

When I build target "ut", the .gcno files show up correctly in the ut.dir tree.

When I tried wrapping CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable with BUILD_TESTING (based on other SO posts), neither the devcpp-lib-template or ut targets get the .gcno coverage files.

```
if (BUILD_TESTING)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
endif ()
```

How do I get only the "ut" target to have the profile-arcs and test-coverage flags?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The problem is the use of cmake commands like set() and include_directories(). These effect the global environment for all builds.

A better pattern in cmake is to use target_include_directories() and target_compile_options() for all targets.

For example, this works. The source project has no coverage tags and no .gcno files, and the ut project has coverage tags, and the .gcno files are generated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

project(devcpp-lib-template)

# === src related
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        lib/library_name.h lib/library_name.cpp
        <snip other source files...>   
)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        -O2)

# === Unit Tests
project(ut)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        lib/library_name.h lib/library_name.cpp
        <snip other files>                    
        ut/ut_test1.cpp
)
target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        -g -fprofile-arcs-ftest-coverage)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
        pthread
        gcov
)
```

Note the shuffle. The target_xx commands have to be put after the add_executable() command (even though the project() is declared first).

The design pattern is:

```
 ...global declarations here...
project(proj1)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE file1, file2, ...)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE dir1 ...)
target_compile_option(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opt1 ...)

project(proj2)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE file1, file2, ...)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE dir1 ...)
target_compile_option(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opt1 ...)

etc.
```

Note that ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} is automatically updated when a project() is declared.